# Google android device manager Rest API?

Tags: android, rest

Google provides a [web app](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager)  that we can use to ring our Android phone when we  accidentally lose our device. 
I searched a long time for the Rest API behind this service to be able to do it by myself programmatically from my own script.

I [found something about mobile device API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-mobile-devices), but it seems it is reserved to "Google Apps for Business" users. Can I use this anyway with a standart google+/gmail accounts?

Is there a way to do this from another app maybe? I've heard about tasker remote.

Any help will be highly appreciable.

Comment: This is the wrong forum for this kind of broad question.

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm a asker beginner :)

Comment: Hi Nicolas, have you find the answer for this query ? Are you posted this query anywhere ? Because I am also looking for this.